# What does this MIPs code mean?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm struggling to find a good site that explains MIPS and how it works.

The code I am trying to understand is:

```
SW 7000(R0),R1
```

I know SW means save word and that it is saving the value of R1 to memory address 7000. What is the point of (R0)? What does it do?

Is there a good resource for problems I run into similar to this?

Thanks!

Comment: there's no register named "R0" or "R1" in MIPS. The correct name is $name, such as $0, $7, $a0, $s1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here R0 is a register.  Placing it in brackets is indicating that you are using indirect addressing (ie: like a pointer) :  not storing in R0, but in the address stored in R0.

The 7000 indicates an offset.  In this case you would have the address stored in R0 + 7000.

Comment: In the version of MIPS I am using, it says R0 is always 0. Is this code unnecessary then? Could I do something like SW 7000,R1?

Comment: the instruction requires a register so using r0 basically means use the immediate as the address...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it should be

```
SW R1, 7000(R0)
```

where R1 and R0 are any MIPS registers.

It would read as store the contents of register R1 into effective memory address `7000+R0`.
E.g. if R1 contains value 10 and R0 contains value 1192, then it would store a word (32 bits) with value 10 into memory address 8192.

Comment: No. Gusbro has it correct. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Integer.

Comment: in fact it should be `sw $1, 7000($0)`